# Regression of y on x and x on y for SSE=0

Tags: statistics, regression

Question: Suppose ($x_i$, $y_i$), i=$1,...,n$ is a set of pairs of observations. Consider the simple linear regressions of y on and x on y. Show that SSE=$0$ for both models if and only if both regressions produce the same line. SSE denotes the sum of squared residual.

I understand that SSE measures of how much variation in y is left unexplained by the model- that is how much cannot be attributed to a linear relationship.

Also, SSE=$0$, correlation coefficient = $1$.

But how to prove that they have the same line?

Comment: They both pass through $(\bar x, \bar y)$, so you have to check the slope. Then find out what it implies for $R^2$.

Comment: Hi, but they will both have different slopes, is it? One will be more steeper than the other one. For this question, $R^2$ cannot be found because they are no numerical values or could you guide me on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the $SSE$ is zero for both models, then the points are aligned (and are neither vertically or horizontally aligned), therefore the regression line passes through the points, and it's the same line for both models.

For the other implication, introduce the equation of the two regression lines. For the regression of $y$ on $x$, let the regression line be $y=ax+b$.
Likewise, for the regression of $x$ on $y$, it's $x=a'y+b'$, but I prefer to write it $y=\frac{1}{a'}x-\frac{b'}{a'}$.

Since both lines pass through the point $(\bar x,\bar y)$, they are identical iff they have the same slope, i.e. if $a=\frac{1}{a'}$, or equivalently if $aa'=1$.

You can check that for the least squares solution, $a=\frac{cov(x,y)}{var(x)}$ and $a'=\frac{cov(x,y)}{var(y)}$.

Hence

$$aa'=\left(\frac{cov(x,y)}{\sigma_X\cdot\sigma_Y}\right)^2$$

That is, $aa'=R^2$. If the regression lines are identical, we have therefore $R^2=1$, hence the SSE is zero.

Comment: If I understand you well, if I used the two regression lines while bearing in mind SSE=0, I should be being able to plot x on y and y on x providing myself with the same line. Actually, I want to show it mathematically. It should work, is it?

Comment: @Eliana There is not much to show: if $SSE=0$, the regression line has to pass through all data points. There is a single line passing through two given distinct points.

Comment: thank you a lot for your explanation. It was very helpful. Very grateful to you